# upgrading from python2.7 to python3.7 in google app engine and ndb datastore

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

We have an existing application on Python 2.7 on Google app engine standard. We are planning to migrate the application to python 3.7 because of end of support for python 2.7.

We use ndb library to access datastore.

According to documentation [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/using-cloud-datastore) it says we should "consider" using Cloud NDB instead of Datastore mode client library.

My question - is "Datastore mode client library" an option for applications migrating from python2.7 / ndb datastore to python 3.7/Firestore Datastore mode? Can I use it instead of "Cloud NDB"? The reason being, if we are going through migration to python 3.7 we might as well use the latest library (Datastore model client library) instead of "Cloud NDB".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Cloud NDB](https://pypi.org/project/google-cloud-ndb/) is designed to be as close as possible to a drop-in replacement for App Engine NDB, to ease migration for existing users. It is essentially a compatibility layer for the NDB library API built on top of the Datastore mode client library. If you'd prefer to skip the NDB layer entirely and use the Datastore mode client library directly, you can certainly do so.

Comment: My datastore has not been migrated to Firestore Datastore mode yet. Google says they will be migrated sometime in the future automatically. It is still the "old" Datastore.  Can I still use Datastore mode client library to connect to the "old" Datatstore after I upgrade my Google App Engine Standard to Python 3.7?

Comment: You should be able to use exactly the same code and client libraries to access either Datastore mode Firestore or legacy Datastore.

Answer (score 3):

NDB is currently being "upgraded" to work with Python 3.7. It's currently in beta and so definitely not recommended for production purposes even though it's pretty much in an advanced state. You won't be able to just drop it in without any adjustments since some "deep" features are being discarded but you still might get satisfied with it's current state.
Consider exploring the source code : https://github.com/googleapis/python-ndb